# Apache vhost returns two different sites

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

I have two sub domains configured on server (main and staging) and for staging it is returning two different paths. Sometimes it is returning correct (`/var/www/html_staging`) but sometimes (when you refresh web browser couple of times or when you go to subpage) it is returning main website (`/var/www/html`)

Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

There are 3 vhosts configurations, two for main website and one for staging. There is a redirect from http to https in vhost config for port 80.

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName website.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin info@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName website.example.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!EXP:!NULL:!ADH:!LOW
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.example.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bundle.crt

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

staging.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName websitestaging.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html_staging

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName websitestaging.example.com
        ServerAdmin info@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html_staging

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!EXP:!NULL:!ADH:!LOW
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/*.example.com.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bundle.crt

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Output of `apache2ctl -S`

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server website.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost website.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost websitestaging.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/staging.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server website.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost website.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost websitestaging.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/staging.conf:15)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

What's the reason for this behaviour? Why only sometimes staging is loading website from correct path and sometimes it is loading from main path? Main website it loaded correctly, this affects only staging.

Comment: Check /var/log/apache2/access.log to be sure the right hostname is being called, since if an unknown hostname is asked for, the first virtual host is served by default. Turn up LogLevel to see how Apache is resolving the request to a file name.

Comment: Output of error.log with `LogLevel trace2`: [error.log](https://pastebin.com/dGu1JWRU) Output of access.log: [access.log](https://pastebin.com/hGG56XrJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you have the same problem as explained above. Just restart whole server, not just apache. After server reboot everything works correctly. There was probably some kind of cache or configuration that hasn't beed removed properly and it was affecting whole server.